# Font Problem in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting

I'm going to be spending some time working in Habenero Java, a minor variant of regular Java, and to make my life easier, I'm trying to define an Emacs mode to work with it.

Right now, all I'm trying to do is define a new major mode that inherits from Java and adds three new keywords: `finish`, `async`, and `forall`. This is what I have so far:

```
(define-derived-mode hj-mode java-mode "Habanero Java"
  "Major mode for Habanero Java."
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil `((,(regexp-opt '("finish" "async" "forall")) .
     font-lock-keyword-face))))
```

The problem I'm having is that Emacs apparently cannot distinguish between these new keywords and a variable declaration. If I write `async { x(); }` then Emacs highlights it correctly. But if I write the equivalent `async x();`, then Emacs fontifies it as if I were declaring a variable by the name `async`.

Does anyione know how to resolve this? The frustration over this is killing me.

Comment: When I was fiddling with csharp-mode, which like Java-mode is based on cc-mode, I needed to wade neck deep in the cc-mode logic in order to determine what was happening. I learned that (a) there are some special cases for Java in the cc-mode parsing logic. (b) there are several different classes of keywords defined for Java-mode; maybe adding "finish" etc to those other classes will work. and (c) tweaking cc-mode is hard.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change your keyword element to the `(matcher . subexp-highlighter)` format where `subexp` is `0` and `override` is `t`:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil `((,(regexp-opt '("finish" "async" "forall"))
   0 font-lock-keyword-face t)
```

More information can be found at:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification